# What is the maximum size of string which we can store on solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, string

Is there a limit to the size of a string that we can store on the Ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum size string you can store would be long enough to fit within the block gas limit (minus the transaction overhead and other costs associated with the transaction).

The [current](https://etherscan.io/block/11500576) block gas limit is ~12.5 million. A *very* rough estimate says that the string length can be approximately 12k characters before it fills the block.

Comment: You can always append more data to an existing string, but for long strings (> 512 bytes) the memory cost may grow exponentially.